# What modules are best to imitate selenium style of being able to login into accounts and place orders? Without opening web browser

Tags: python, api, beautifulsoup, automation, bots

I want to create a bot to purchase items when restocked. For example I want to buy a certain item on amazon when it becomes available. I can do this with selenium quite easy yet I want to be able to run this bot off a raspberry pi and would love a more efficient way of running it. I know you can do this via an API but most retail websites don't have APIs.

I know you can get urls and other page info using beautiful soup, yet does bs4 allow me to pass information onto the browser and submit?

Would love some recommendations on best libraries to use to achieve this process. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Maybe consider creating a microservice that runs in the cloud that has functions to do the scraping and then have the PI call the microservice functions?